# Samsung laptop in 'repair' boot loop after updating to Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, laptop, boot

I downloaded Windows 8 successfully and a restart option appeared on screen. I was on a browser and clicked the restart button without closing the browser. The computer continued to restarted and it went through two loading processes that went to 100%. It then said getting ready... for a long long time. I thought it froze and I turned off the computer and turned back on the computer. It then said "Repairing Disk Errors. This may take over an hour to complete." I let it sit for over 12 hours and nothing happened. I've tried multiple times to restart the computer, but it still keeps saying ought it froze and I turned off the computer and turned back on the computer. It then said "Repairing Disk Errors. This may take over an hour to complete."

I attempted to get into safe mode by using F8 and Shift+F8 and nothing happened. I tried removing the hard drive from the laptop, putting it into an external enclosure, and trying to see it in another computer (three computers to be specific). But that didn't work. It recognized it as a "device of some sort", but when I looked in the Windows Explorer, there was no external hard drive I could interact with. Though, it was visible in the Device Manager.

The laptop was a Samsung ATIV Book 4 (NP470R5E-K01UB).

Answer (score -1):

Googling, it seems a very common problem (Google your title).

It could be the MBR (Master Boot Record) has got corrupted, installed in the wrong place or it's seemingly likely that the Samsung laptops aren't keen on Win 8.1.

The only suggestion *I* can recommend, and [MS](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/windows-81-after-installation-stuck-on-restart/029daeea-b6cf-447a-bbb4-85f9c781acad) is too, reinstall the laptop to Windows 8 - Vanilla (I.E not 8.1).

Although not the best of solutions - I hope this helps.

[Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Samsung%20laptop%20in%20%27repair%27%20boot%20loop%20after%20updating%20to%20Windows%208.1&oq=Samsung%20laptop%20in%20%27repair%27%20boot%20loop%20after%20updating%20to%20Windows%208.1&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)
[TomsHardware](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1716466/stuck-boot-loop-updating-win.html)

Edit: Spelling, grammar & links.